# Web application using JSF-Front end and node.js-Back end

Tags: java, node.js, jsf, real-time

I'm planning to build a eCommerce web application(similar to http://zovi.com/) using JSF 1.2 and node.js. All front end components will be jsf components binding to backing bean. I want to achieve real time functionality ( such as displaying **Today's hot sellers** ,**Customers who viewed this item also viewed** such patterns) using node.js. And all data retrievals from database(MySQL)should be accomplished using node and display in JSF components. I'm confused in how to bind data that i get from node to corresponding managed bean property(since i bound it to corresponding JSF component). Hope you understand this context. Please suggest some solutions.

And I heard performance of Node.js is efficient only for small web applications not for Enterprise level. Is my approach  correct??

Answer (score 3):

I would stick to a Java EE or Node.js application. I don't see any benefits from combining these two technologies. To run a JSF application (I would recommend JSF2 instead of 1.2) you have to run a Java Application Server, which is great system resources consumer. So in the end you will have to run Node.js and Java server at the same time...
But if you would insist on using both technologies, the web services like REST API will be a solution.
Never used Node.js, but what I heard of it has much better performance compared to Java App. servers.

Comment: Thanks for your respose :) I got your point. But I've to use node.js for CRUD operations.

Comment: In this case I would recommend using some Service Oriented Architecture like REST or SOAP for communication between your Node.js and Java servers. Or implement it all in Node.js as far as I know it is server and client side technology.

Comment: >`Never used Node.js, but what I heard of it has much better performance compared to Java App. servers.` - That better performance doesn't really show at the benchmarks done here:  http://www.techempower.com/benchmarks/#section=data-r4 Node is consistently in the middle tier or even last tear, never a winner. Servlet is always faster according to that benchmark.

Comment: Thank you for providing this link. Node.js looks here like out-of-date platform. I wonder how would these frameworks behave in higher requests loads like hundreds per second rates.